# no module named yaml

Tags: ros, python, yaml, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS Team,

I have tried to install ROS on my Mac after having installed Macports etc as explained, and after typing "rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no" in the terminal, I get the error message: ImportError: No module named yaml.

Do you have a hint?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10028/no-module-named-yaml/) by [mariamaria](https://answers.ros.org/users/579/mariamaria/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found that the soln described here works. Note that I had to open a new window to get the rosinstall command to work after taking all these steps - apparently, the path still wasn't being rehashed properly.

http://answers.ros.org/question/385/problem-with-mac-os-installation-with-yaml

It's ugly, and I don't like removing system files - but it worked.

---

Originally posted by [ralph](https://answers.ros.org/users/580/ralph/) with karma: 16 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're following the diamondback installation directions, you'll have python setuptools installed. With that you can run easy_install. We found that if you run sudo easy_install PyYAML this will install the right version of yaml.

---

Originally posted by [Perchik](https://answers.ros.org/users/643/perchik/) with karma: 13 on 2011-06-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem on Ubuntu after upgrading from 10.10 to 11.04 my solution:

```
sudo aptitude install python-setuptools
sudo aptitude install python-yaml
```

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-06-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1